# Aligning two separate equations without \intertext

Tags: align, amsmath

How do I align the `\Rightarrow` commands of these separate equations? Please note that the `\hspace{7.5cm}` commands of the second equation are my attempt at manual adjustment. Also, I know that there are many other queries like this one, but the issue I have with the answers is that they suggested placing both equations in one `\align` environment and then using `\intertext`. But this doesn't really work in my case, since I would like to keep the "if" statements on the left margin, just like regular text.

```
If $\delta = \cfrac{1}{\mid l \mid + 1}$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\Rightarrow \ \mid x \mid \ < \ \cfrac{1}{\mid l \mid + 1} \hspace{4cm} &&\text{true statement, as $\delta>0$} \\
&\Rightarrow \ \mid l \mid + 1 \ < \ \mid \cfrac{1}{x} \mid \hspace{4cm} &&\text{t.s.}
\end{alignat*}

If $\epsilon = 1$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\Rightarrow \ \mid \frac{1}{x} - l \mid \ < \ 1 \hspace{7.5cm}\\
&\Rightarrow \ \mid \frac{1}{x} \mid \ < \ 1 + \mid l \mid \hspace{7.5cm}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\hfill a false statement, since it contradicts a true statement
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: you have a misuse of  `alignat*{3}`:   3 &  mean you have *two* alignment columns, not three. More generally, *n* alignment points require *2n – 1* ampersands.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean, because with `\intertext` the text goes at the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

If $\delta = \dfrac{1}{\lvert l\rvert + 1}$
\begin{align*}
&\Rightarrow\quad \lvert x \rvert < \frac{1}{\lvert l \rvert + 1} &&\text{true statement, as $\delta>0$} \\
&\Rightarrow \quad \lvert l \rvert + 1 < \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} \Bigr\rvert &&\text{true statement} \\
\intertext{If $\epsilon = 1$}
&\Rightarrow \quad \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} - l \Bigr\rvert < 1 \\
&\Rightarrow \quad \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} \Bigr\rvert < 1 + \lvert l \rvert
\end{align*}
a false statement, since it contradicts a true statement

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\mid` is not for the absolute value; also `\ <\` adds too much space around the relation symbol.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, using `\intertext{}` is the way to go.

However, if you insist on doing it with two separate `align` environments, you need to insert appropriate `\hphantom{}` spacing.  Here, it was only necessary to add the `\hphantom{}` to the first equation in the second `align`.  In most cases it won't be as simple as this ended up being.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\WidestText}{\text{true statement, as $\delta>0$}}

\begin{document}

If $\delta = \dfrac{1}{\lvert l\rvert + 1}$
\begin{align*}
    &\Rightarrow\quad \lvert x \rvert < \frac{1}{\lvert l \rvert + 1} 
        &&\WidestText 
    \\
    &\Rightarrow \quad \lvert l \rvert + 1 < \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} \Bigr\rvert 
        &&\text{true statement}
\end{align*}
If $\epsilon = 1$
\begin{align*}
    &\Rightarrow \quad \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} - l \Bigr\rvert < 1 && \hphantom{\WidestText} \\
    &\Rightarrow \quad \Bigl\lvert \frac{1}{x} \Bigr\rvert < 1 + \lvert l \rvert
\end{align*}
a false statement, since it contradicts a true statement.
\end{document}
```